# Page fully re-rendered event?

Tags: javascript, webkit

I'm altering the DOM tree in plain JS and need to know when the changes get fully rendered on screen (mostly care about document dimensions).

```
window.onload=function(){
    ss = document.styleSheets[0];
    for(i = 0; i < ss.cssRules.length; i++) { ss.deleteRule(i) };
    ss.addRule('p', 'color: red;')
    // ... many more
    // call some other function when the page is fully rendered?
}
```

TIA.

Comment: I don't know if there's an event that fires after images and whatnot are loaded, and those could change the dimensions of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have settled on

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
// code
}, 50);
```

so far.

Answer (score 0):

why don't use jQuery ? it provides that functionality and can help you a lot.

Comment: This runs on a mobile device, so I'd prefer not to add dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

MyLibrary (i.e. your library) provides a documentready listener:

http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib-doc.asp#attachdocumentreadylistener >